# how to enable metrics in Flink 1.11

Tags: apache-flink

I'm new to flink and i'm trying to upgrade from flink 1.8 to flink 1.11 on an emr cluster. after upgrading to flink1.11 One of the difference that i see is i don't get any metrics. i found out that flink 1.11 do not have **org.apache.flink.metrics.statsd.StatsDReporterFactory** jar in /usr/lib/flink/opt which was the case for flink 1.8. could anyone has any pointer to locate **org.apache.flink.metrics.statsd.StatsDReporterFactory** jar or how to use metrics in flink.1.11?

Comment: Have you tried to download the jar https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-metrics-statsd into the lib directory?

Comment: I tried copying jar in the plugins folder but it didn't worked. Application is runnning but i don't get jobmanger/taskmanger logs.

Comment: Logging and metrics are unrelated from Flink's point of view. Your question was about metrics and the statsd metrics reporter. Metrics sent to the statsd daemon are often aggregated and monitored in some metrics backend, such as graphite.

Answer (score -1):

Flink has moved to a plugin model for managing filesystems (as of Flink 1.10) and metrics reporters (this changed in 1.11). See the [Flink 1.11 release notes](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/release-notes/flink-1.11.html#converted-all-metricreporters-to-plugins-flink-16963) for details, but in short, metrics reporters should no longer be placed into the lib directory, but in plugins/<some_directory> instead.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/monitoring/metrics.html#reporter also covers this topic:

> Important: The jar containing the reporter must be accessible when Flink is started. Reporters that support the factory.class property can be loaded as plugins. Otherwise the jar must be placed in the /lib folder. Reporters that are shipped with Flink (i.e., all reporters documented on this page) are available by default.

Comment: I agree and i did the same. I download the jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-metrics-statsd and put it in a plugins folder (/usr/lib/flink/plugins/statsd) but it not showing any jobmanager/taskmanger logs.